# Trait location in bundle Symfony 2 project

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, bundle

I have a design doubt about Symfony 2. The fact is I want to use a trait into a bundle of mine but I am not sure where to locate the trait. It is not a controller, it is not a model or entity.

I have a solutions on mind but I am not sure if it follows the best practice. The idea is create a new folder called /Trait. It is correct?

```
<your-bundle>/
├─ AcmeBlogBundle.php
├─ Controller/
├─ Entity/
├─ Trait/ <- My thought
├─ README.md
├─ LICENSE
├─ Resources/
│   ├─ config/
│   ├─ doc/
│   │  └─ index.rst
│   ├─ translations/
│   ├─ views/
│   └─ public/
└─ Tests/
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your `Trait` created to add specific field(s) in your Entities?

Comment: No, it is for add some generic functionalities for my controllers

Comment: Interface(s) would be better, no?

Comment: @miguel, I think, the best solution to create BaseController and extend your controller from BaseController.

Comment: scoolnico in that case I don't want to use an interface because it is not a matter of contract or specification.

@Viktor the idea to use a BaseController come to my mind but i discarded because of implementation matters.

Imagine guys that I need to put a Trait, not a workaround, so... what is the best option? Doesn't matter if I need it or not, that should be out of the equation, I need to use a Trait, so what is the best option? you considere that is ok?

Comment: Interface wouldn't have any functions, just intentions. If your traits are for specifics types of class (controllers) then it might make sense to put them in the corresponding namespace `Acme\BlogBundle\Controller\Traits`.

Comment: Sounds very nice @qooplmao, thank you :-)

Comment: Also I don't think you can have `Trait` as a namespace so you might, annoyingly, have to revert to using the plural just for the traits. Alternative you could just have them in the controllers directory but just with the Trait suffix like `Acme\BlogBundle\Controller\SomethingAboutTheSpecificFunctionsTrait`.

Comment: Ok, undestand, very interesting detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Trait`, since it's a php keyword, so you'll have to use `Traits`, but apart from that, your suggestion is fine.

Bundle structure is only there for your convenience, it shouldn't be something limiting you, feel free to create any namespaces as you like. In fact you can [use Symfony without bundles at all](http://elnur.pro/symfony-without-bundles/).

Comment: I myself would not use Traits as it is too generic of a term.  Sort of like making a directory called Classes and then sticking all your class files under it.  Perhaps the question could be updated with a description of your specific trait.